# javascript Uint8Array access doesn't return expected result (compared with expanding out the contents of the array in chrome console)

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

When I console.log my Uint8Array to the chrome dev console, I can expand out its contents and view all the elements. When I console.log an access to that array, say array[512], I don't see what I saw when I expanded it out.

Example taken directly from my source code:

```
console.log(this.memory);      // logs [0, 0, 0, ......]
console.log(this.memory[512]); // logs 0
```

When I expand out the array from the first log, I can see that index 512 has the value 34, NOT 0.

Here is a screenshot from my console:

[image]

Right below that, the number 0 is logged from when I logged this.memory[512]. I tried running through the array with a for-loop to make double sure. That logged out all 0's! I don't know what else to try.

Update: Even more weirdness. I attached the array to window to play around with it in console:

```
window.memory = this.memory
// now in chrome, lets see what happens
window.memory[512];
-> 34
```

Here is a jsfiddle with pretty much all my code. The strangeness is happening around lines 113-116. It is a work in progress chip8 emulator: https://jsfiddle.net/ybd6ntks/2/

Update 2: If I run `window.memory[512];` from my source code, I get 0. If I run `window.memory[512];` from within chrome console, I get 34.

Comment: That's weird behavior for sure, could your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) for us to help you debug it?

Comment: Is `this.memory` rapidly changing? In Chrome, `console.log` is asynchronous. When you do `console.log(memory)`, Chrome may not get around to displaying element 512's value until *after* it displays the result of `console.log(memory[512])`, because the latter is much faster to access and display. In all likelihood the value has changed by the time Chrome is able to display the large array. A workaround, albeit a relatively poor one, is to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(memory))`.

Comment: @Jordan I tried your suggestion, I got the same results.

Comment: @vihan1086 jsfiddle is up: https://jsfiddle.net/ybd6ntks/2/

Comment: @Jordan my mistake! When stringifying the array, it appears to contain all 0's. What does this mean?

Comment: When you `console.log(obj)` and **after that** you'll do `obj.propName = 'ala'` and inspect the object contents in console **by expanding it** you'll see an updated object property. That's how dev tools behave.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was an async issue. I fixed it by waiting until I knew for sure that the array had been updated completely before moving on with the program. I set a flag on the last byte, and checked if it was set or not. If not, I setTimeout and tried again.